# Business Review Summary in Embedded Google Map

Tags: google-maps

I have a Google Map embedded on a contact page of a website. Right now it shows a marker where the business is. However, it also shows a text phrase summary of the reviews. I want to know if there is a way I can disable the review summary from the pin on the map?

**EMBED CODE**

```
<iframe id="contactMap" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2951.8670636802526!2d-83.75118700000002!3d42.281361000000004!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x883cae3d39e0b9af%3A0x17003eed7e7a0b70!2sLIVE!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1407618823763" width="505" height="275" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

**SCREEN SHOT OF REVIEW SUMMARY ON MAP**

The Review Summary says "hip hop - drink specials".

[image]

Comment: @MrUpsidown why did you take out the google-maps-api tag? If there is a way of doing it through the API that might help.

Comment: Because this is not related to the Javascript Maps API v3. If you mentioned in your question that you wanted to do it with the API, then it should be tagged as you did.

Comment: I didn't mention in my question that I wanted to do it with the API because I'm not sure if it's possible. I'm asking if there is anyway to do it at all. Regardless of methodology.

Comment: Just add it back if you think it makes sense. No worries.

Comment: Btw. I just tested the iframe code you posted and I see no review summary.